# Rise of the Tomb Raider survival cache

Tags: rise-of-the-tomb-raider

Can someone please explain how to get to this one?  It's driving me insane.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PzCT.jpg

Comment: Not sure if you have done the optional side mission to save some prisoners...but I am pretty sure you can get to it when you go to rescue them. It gives you access to another couple rooms, and that looks like one of the areas. If you notice the little island near that, that is how you get to the outside of the building near that area.

Answer (score 1):

You can access that area of the building during and after the side mission "The Unlucky Ones" which has you rescuing some remnant prisoners. You climb up to the back of the building by way of the small island in your picture (near the cave icon). To get this side mission you first have to complete the story mission "Dangerous Territory" which has you explore the Soviet Prison in the northwest area of the map.